# Solving a homogeneous system of three ODEs with variable coefficients.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, systems-of-equations

I am interested in solving the following system of ODEs:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x'(t) \\ y'(t) \\z'(t)
\end{pmatrix} = a
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & -B_2 & B_1 \sin \omega t \\
  B_2 & 0&  -B_1 \cos \omega t \\
  -B_1 \sin \omega t & B_1 \cos \omega t &  0
 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x(t) \\ y(t) \\z(t)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

either in MATLAB or analytically, but I have no idea how to do it. I'd appreciate any help on how to deal with this.

Is this even possible to solve analytically btw? The equation is of the form

$$\frac{d{\bf v}(t)}{dt} = a \left( {\bf v}(t) \times {\bf B}(t) \right).$$

EDIT: So is there really no way to solve this in a smart way? Do I have to diagonalize? I don't know how to do it.

Comment: it seems that $|v|^2$ is conserved. why don't you use that reduce your system to a two dimensional system?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by that

Comment: dot product of $v$ and $\frac{dv}{dt}$ is zero. that means the magnitude of $v$ is constant.

Comment: How would I reduce the problem to a 2d one then?

Comment: i am looking at the vector equation $\frac{dv}{dt}= a v \times B.$ is $B$ a constant vector or does it depend on $t?$? if it is constant, then you can write the vector equation as matrix equation with a constant an antisymmetric matrix. from there you can solve.

Comment: No, $B(t)$ depends on time.

Comment: then the best way is to define two angle variables $\theta, \phi$ so that $v = |v|(\sin \theta \cos \phi, \sin \theta \sin \phi, \cos \theta)$ derive equations for the angle variables and use the periodicity of the angle variables.

Comment: Any old numerical ODE solver will be able to do this, `ode45` is the standard choice and should work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have Matlab, but here's the Mathematica code to do it:

```
solx =With[{a=1,\[Omega]=1,b2=1,b1=2},
           NDSolve[{x'[t]==-a*b2*y[t]+a*b1*Sin[\[Omega]*t]*z[t],
                    y'[t]==a*b2*x[t]-a*b1*Cos[\[Omega]*t]*z[t],
                    z'[t]==-a*b1*Sin[\[Omega]*t]*x[t]+a*b1*Cos[\[Omega]*t]*y[t],
                    x[0]==1,y[0]==0,z[0]==0},
                    {x,y,z},{t,0,20}]]
ParametricPlot3D[{Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. solx]}, {t, 0, 20}]
```

I plotted this for a few $\mathbf{v}(0) = (0,0,1), (0,1,0)$, and $(1,0,0)$, giving the following:[image]

Comment: That's very artistic.

Comment: it's missing a term: z'[t] = ...*x[t] + ...

Comment: Nice catch; fixed!

Answer (score 1):

You can make a change of coordinate basis which diagonalises the $3\times 3$ matrix in the RHS. Then you will be able to solve this as three uncoupled DEs for your transformed basis. This will then give you a system of equations to solve for your original functions (or you may find that working in the transformed basis is more convenient anyway).

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on how to find that coordinate change?

Comment: This is called the eigenbasis of the matrix. The elements of the diagonal will be the eigenvalues of your matrix, and the new basis vectors will be the corresponding eigenvectors.

Comment: How do I find the eigenbasis?

Comment: The eigenvectors of an operator $A$ are those vectors $x$ which satisfy $A x = \lambda x$ for some constant $\lambda$ (this is the eigenvalue). You can find all the valid $\lambda$s as the solutions to $\mathrm{det}(A - \lambda I) = 0$ as a polynomial in $\lambda$. The wikipedia page on eigenvalues and eigenvectors is a good place to start if you are still confused.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Python implementation of the [midpoint method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_method), which unfortunately doesn't exploit the skew-symmetric nature of the operator except as an assertion that $\left|\mathbf{v}(t)\right|^{2}$ is constant. I've been looking for an excuse to learn `Matplotlib`; this is somewhat of a minimal working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""This script parses user parameters, solves a deq using the modified Euler method,
and then displays the result using Matplotlib"""

import argparse, matplotlib, mpl_toolkits, numpy, math, matplotlib.pyplot

class ModifiedEulerMethod(object):
    """This uses the modified Euler method to solve a 3d first-order deq."""
    def __init__(self, a, B1, B2, w, x0, y0, z0, t_max, h):
        self.a = a
        self.B1 = B1
        self.B2 = B2
        self.w = w
        self.x0 = x0
        self.y0 = y0
        self.z0 = z0
        self.t_max = t_max
        self.h = h
        assert t_max > 10*h
        self.x = numpy.empty(t_max/h)
        self.x.fill(x0)
        self.y = numpy.empty(t_max/h)
        self.y.fill(y0)
        self.z = numpy.empty(t_max/h)
        self.z.fill(z0)
        self.x[0] = x0
        self.y[0] = y0
        self.z[0] = z0
        self.v_sq = x0**2+y0**2+z0**2

    def run(self):
        """Calculates solution to deq using modified Euler Method.
        Uses: v_{n+1} = v_{n} + h*f(t_n+h/2, v_{n} + h*f(t_n,v_n)/2)"""
        aB2 = self.a*self.B2
        aB1 = self.a*self.B1
        for n in range(0, len(self.x)-1):
            t_n = n*self.h
            #First evaluate h*f(t_n, v_n)/2:
            sinwt = math.sin(self.w*t_n)
            coswt = math.cos(self.w*t_n)
            fx = 0.5*self.h**2*(-aB2*self.y[n]+aB1*sinwt*self.z[n])
            fy = 0.5*self.h**2*(aB2*self.x[n] -aB1*coswt*self.z[n])
            fz = 0.5*self.h**2*(-aB1*sinwt*self.x[n]+aB1*coswt*self.y[n])
            #v_{n} + h*f(t_n, v_n)/2:
            arg_x = self.x[n] + fx
            arg_y = self.y[n] + fy
            arg_z = self.z[n] + fz
            #Now evaluate h*f(t_n+h/2, arg_v):
            sinwt = math.sin(self.w*(t_n+0.5*self.h))
            coswt = math.cos(self.w*(t_n+0.5*self.h))
            self.x[n+1] = self.x[n]+self.h*(-aB2*arg_y+aB1*sinwt*arg_z)
            self.y[n+1] = self.y[n]+self.h*(aB2*arg_x -aB1*coswt*arg_z)
            self.z[n+1] = self.z[n]+self.h*(-aB1*sinwt*arg_x+aB1*coswt*arg_y)
            if abs(self.x[n+1]**2 + self.y[n+1]**2 + self.z[n+1]**2-self.v_sq) > 0.1:
                print("No further values will be calculated as the conservation law |v|^2 = const has drifted further than tolerance.\n")
                print("This occurred at time t={}".format(t_n))
                break


    def display(self):
        """Uses Matplotlib to display the solution as a parametric curve."""
        from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
        matplotlib.pyplot.style.use('dark_background')
        fig = matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
        ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
        ax.plot(self.x, self.y, self.z)
        ax.set_xlabel('x axis')
        ax.set_ylabel('y axis')
        ax.set_zlabel('z axis')
        matplotlib.pyplot.show()

def main():
    """Parses arguments, runs simulation, plots results."""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Solves v\' = aB(t)xv(t)')
    parser.add_argument('-a', '--a', help='Real number', default=1.0, type=float)
    parser.add_argument('-B1', '--B1', help='Real number', default=1.0, type=float)
    parser.add_argument('-B2', '--B2', help='Real number', default=1.0, type=float)
    parser.add_argument('-w', '--w', help='Angular frequency', default=1.0, type=float)
    parser.add_argument('-x0', '--x0', help='Initial x-coordinate', default=1.0, type=float)
    parser.add_argument('-y0', '--y0', help='Initial y-coordinate', default=0.0, type=float)
    parser.add_argument('-z0', '--z0', help='Initial z-coordinate', default=0.0, type=float)
    parser.add_argument('--t_max', help='Maximum time to run the simulation', default=7.0, type=float)
    parser.add_argument('--time_step', help='Time step', default=0.005, type=float)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    simulation = ModifiedEulerMethod(args.a, args.B1, args.B2, args.w, args.x0, args.y0, args.z0, args.t_max, args.time_step)

    simulation.run()
    simulation.display()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The following is the output with

```
script.py --B2=5 --t_max=10 --time_step=0.0005
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As abel suggests, since $|\mathbf{v}(t)|^{2}$ is conserved, then this suggests spherical coordinates (as $r$ will be constant). Using the convention $x(t) = r\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi)$, $y = r\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)$, $z = r\cos(\phi)$, we have
\begin{align}
\dot{x}(t) &= -r\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)\dot{\theta} + r\cos(\theta)\cos(\phi)\dot{\phi} \\
\dot{y}(t) &= r\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi)\dot{\theta} + r\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)\dot{\phi} \\
\dot{z}(t) &= -r\sin(\phi)\dot{\phi}
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
-\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)\dot{\theta} + \cos(\theta)\cos(\phi)\dot{\phi} 
&= -aB_{2}\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi) +aB_{1}\sin(\omega t)\cos(\phi) \\
\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi)\dot{\theta} + \sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)\dot{\phi} 
&=a B_{2}\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi) - aB_{1}\cos(\omega t)\cos(\phi) \\
\dot{\phi}
&=
aB_{1}(\sin(\omega t)\cos(\theta) - \cos(\omega t)\sin(\theta))
\end{align}
If I haven't made any mistakes (unlikely; edit plz!) we get the 2-D system
\begin{align}
\dot{\theta}
&=
a(B_{2} - B_{1}(\cos(\omega t)\cot(\phi)/\cos(\theta)
+\sin(\theta)\cot(\phi)\sin(\omega t) - \sin(\theta)\cot(\phi)\cos(\omega t)\tan(\theta)))\\
\dot{\phi}
&=
aB_{1}(\sin(\omega t)\cos(\theta) - \cos(\omega t)\sin(\theta))
\end{align}
This system is *way worse* than the original.